# How to prevent form reset in drupal 7 when captcha entered is invalid?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, recaptcha

We are trying to enable functionality of reCaptcha in user registration form. (User is added in LDAP once registration is successful.)

Here is the issue:
1. User enters value in form fields
2. User enters wrong captcha text.
3. Captcha validation is done over AJAX call, which returns failure.
4. Form is reloaded with message like captcha is invalid
5. Values are lost (even userid ie email)

How do we fix this?